# Show latest and related articles from 3 different blogs

Tags: plugins

Say I have 3 sites, abc.com, def.com and xyz.com. And all the 3 sites have different wordpress installation and different databases. Now What I want to show all the latest articles of all three sites in sidebar of main site say abc.com. Secondly in story page I want that related articles should come from all the three sites. Is this possible from any plugin?
I am not talking about multisite.

Regards
Girish

Answer (score 0):

@franp. is correct, but in case you want to go a code route here's how you get an RSS Feed of a website. You can duplicate this as you see fit, or combine multiple into an array etc.

**Let's get our RSS Feed from ABC.com**

```
$rss = fetch_feed('http://abc.com/feed');   // Or where ever that websites feeds are located. You can add query variables to narrow down categories too.
if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ){               // If the feed exists we can do some stuff like limit how many we need.
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity( 10 );      // return 10 or if there is not 10 posts, return the max posts found.
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems );   // Get posts sub 0 through posts sub $maxitems
}
```

**Now let's list our RSS Feed, if there is one**

```
<ul id="delicious_feed">
    <?php if ( $maxitems == 0 ) : ?>
        <li>No Items Found.</li>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink. ?>
        <?php foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : $i++; ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>" target="_blank"
                    title="<?php printf( __( 'Posted %s', 'my-text-domain' ), $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a') ); ?>">
                    <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?>
                </a>
                <?php $item->get_description(); ?>...
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with the rss/atom importer, just add a rss widget in your main site abc.com sidebar with the feed of def.com and xyz.com.

Go to the main site widget administration panel: abc.com/wp-admin/widgets.php 
Add the RSS widget by dragging it from the left column to the sidebar on the right. To configure it you have to copy in it the rss syndication (feed) from the other page, say def.com/feed/.

Add as many RSS widgets as you like, each one with a feed from an external site.